# How to Check if a User/Page is Connected to the Internet with ASP Classic for Offline Development?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I'm fairly familiar with the language but this concept is a puzzle to me.  I am wanting ot check if the server on which the script is running can access the internet for development so let's say if I am just working on the site offline on my own server with everything I need but internet access.  Catch my drift?  Thank you.

Comment: I assume your ASP page is accessible on the internet? If they can load your page, then they are on the internet. :)

Comment: I agree with Red this question is Non Sequitur, please clarify.

Comment: I agree with Red and Anthony, also, asp is running on server side... not in client side. time ago i did the same, a simple html page that shows the message: "Yes, you have internet" (http://testinternet.xhiena.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try and ping a site like this: (not tested)

```
url = "www.google.com"
Set objWShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objCmd = objWShell.Exec("ping " & url)
strPingResult = objCmd.StdOut.Readall()
set objCmd = nothing 
set objWShell = nothing

strStatus = "offline"

if InStr(strPingResult,"TTL=") > 0 then strStatus = "online"

response.write url & " is " & strStatus

response.write ".<br>" & replace(strPingResult,vbCrLf,"<br>")
```

Comment: but this runs on server side, with this you can check if your server is online, not the client.

Comment: But if the server is online then people can access it which is basically what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand this correctly, but you could use the [Session](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp) object / [Global.asa](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_globalasa.asp) file > `Session_OnStart` and `Session_OnEnd` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer I posted on this very similar question:

[How to check the availability of internet in classic asp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730440/how-to-check-the-availability-of-internet-in-classic-asp/14766009#14766009)