# How to check the availability of internet in classic asp?

Tags: asp-classic, internet-connection

I am calling a webservice in my code. I want to add a validation to check whether internet connection is available or not.

If internet connection is not available then it should prompt that internet connection is not available.

Please provide me the code to check this.

Comment: You can use my `CheckServerPulse` method, it can be found [here](http://forums.aspfree.com/net-development-11/checking-servers-status-48576.html). (just pass the IP of the server hosting your web service)

Comment: I donot have the access to the server where I have hosted the web service. Please suggest me another method.

Comment: You don't need access to the server, you need only its IP address. The rest is done by the classic ASP code.

Answer (score 0):

try to ping the destination server and see the result, if you get a reply then continue your request
see the following url http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/network/net-ping-aspnet2-vb.aspx

Comment: She asks for Classic ASP, so maybe instead this: http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-execute-a-ping-command-from-asp-and-retrieve-the-results.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to grab a web page, adjust the timeouts to suit your needs. This assumes the website returns a valid 200 request, if the website is down or returns a 404 or something you might have to adjust.

```
Function GetPage(inURL) ' scrapes the URL page, HTML, XML, JSON, whatever
  Dim O(2), xmlServerHttp, error, ServerStatus, responseText
  Error = False
  Set xmlServerHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    lResolve = 1000
    lConnect = 3500
    lSend = 1000
    lReceive = 2000
  xmlServerHttp.setTimeouts lResolve, lConnect, lSend, lReceive
    On Error Resume Next
  xmlServerHttp.open "GET", inURL, false
  xmlServerHttp.send()
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    ServerStatus="timeout"
    error=True
  Else
    ServerStatus = xmlServerHttp.status
    If ServerStatus = 200 Then responseText=xmlServerHttp.responseText Else error=true
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0
  O(0) = responseText
  O(1) = Error
  O(2) = ServerStatus
  Set xmlServerHttp = nothing
  GetPage=O
End function
```

Usage:

```
 data = GetPage(url)
 body = data(0)
 error = data(1)
 ServerStatus = data(2)

 if error then
   response.write "Sorry no internet"
 else
   response.write "Internet found!"
 end if
```